# How to filter users in mysql database based on their star rating

Tags: php, mysql

So I am Currently working on a project where I need to filter active users based on the star rating from a select input field.

Below is my users table

```
| id | username | firstname | lastname | description | active |
---------------------------------------------------------------
| 2  | kay      | Albert    | Kojo     | Tall        | 1      |
| 3  | kay123   | Mary      | Thompson | Tall        | 1      |
| 4  | kay124   | Francis   | Addai    |             | 1      |
```

Below is my user_reviews table

```
| id | user_id| rating |
------------------------
| 1  |   2    |  5     |
| 2  |   3    |  3     |
```

Below is my current query:

```
$ratings = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['rating']);

SELECT
  *,
  users.id,
  FORMAT(AVG( user_reviews.rating ), 1) AS rating_value,
  count( user_reviews.user_id ) AS review_count 
FROM
  users
  LEFT JOIN user_reviews ON users.id = user_reviews.user_id
WHERE
  users.username LIKE '%%' 
AND users.active = 1 AND (users.description != "" OR users.description IS 
  NOT NULL)
GROUP BY
  users.id 
HAVING
  $ratings <= rating_value
ORDER BY
  review_count DESC
```

The above query only returns users who are found in user_reviews table. I would be very glad if someone can help me retrieve users who are in the user_reviews table and users who are not.

Comment: You should showcase the table schemes and its typical contents. Otherwise unlikely to be answerable just from a convoluted query.

Comment: @mario please I have edited the initial question. I hope this is okay.

Comment: Looks more like Id 4 is not included because it's active=0

Comment: @forbs that was error on my part. I have edited it to reflect that id 4 is also active

Comment: Then the issue is the `HAVING $ratings < rating_value` which I assume you meant `rating` because on the JOIN some will have `rating=NULL` and NULL is not a number and the `<` will fail

Comment: @forbs very true. That's where I am facing the challenge. Anyway to get around it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query:

```
SELECT 
   users.*,
   (SELECT FORMAT(AVG(rating),1) FROM user_reviews where users.id = user_reviews.user_id) AS rating_value,
   (SELECT count(user_id) FROM user_reviews where users.id = user_reviews.user_id) AS review_count
FROM
   users
WHERE 
   users.username LIKE '%%' 
   AND users.active = 1 AND (users.description != "" OR users.description IS 
   NOT NULL)
HAVING
   $rating <= rating_value
ORDER BY
   review_count DESC
```

It will return the output like below:
(Without `HAVING $rating <= rating_value`)

```
| id | username |firstname | lastname | description | active | rating_value | review_count |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2  | kay      | Albert   | Kojo     | Tall        | 1      | 5.0          |  1           |
| 3  | kay123   | Mary     | Thompson | Tall        | 1      | 3.0          |  1           |   
| 4  | kay134   | Francis  | Addai    |             | 1      |  NULL        |  0           |
```

(With `HAVING $rating <= rating_value`, where `$rating == 4`)

```
| id | username |firstname | lastname | description | active | rating_value | review_count |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2  | kay      | Albert   | Kojo     | Tall        | 1      | 5.0          |  1           |
```

Note:
We don't need to use the `GROUP_BY` as the `GROUP_BY` will make your results only show the ones in relation.

Comment: I have edited the user table to include the username field, and changed user with **id 4** is also set to active.

Comment: I just realized your query was not done around the **$ratings** variable.

Comment: Hello, Max, 
I just updated the codes based on what you are questioning. 
Hope it works for you.

Comment: thank you for your efforts so far but I am looking for a way to retrieve all the users. I welcome any suggestions also if you think I should modify the database fields

Comment: Actually, the query above works for all users, as long as you set where users.username LIKE '%%', it will return from all usernames.
Unless you set users.username LIKE '%kay%', then it will only return the results with username '... kay ...'

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
 GROUP BY
   users.id 
 HAVING
   $ratings <= rating_value
```

To

```
 GROUP BY
   users.id 
 HAVING
   (rating >= $ratings or rating IS NULL )
```

That should solve your missing records.